# Facebook sdk 3.8.0. for android after re-login Request.newMeRequest returns user that is null; java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an android application which has been using the Facebook sdk for 5 months now. Everything used to work fine until I logged out on a new device that had been successfully logged in. After that I successfully logged in, but when I tried to get the user’s information using the Request.newMeRequest I got null. So I debugged the problem and here is what I found out:

1. The session was successfully created with an access token
2. When trying to call the newMeRequest somewhere in the facebook sdk an exception was raised. The exception is “java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed”

I don’t understand how it is possible that the socket is closed. I searched a lot on the internet and here are some of the suggestions and things I tried to remove the bug:

1. I reinstalled the app and cleared all the cached data
2. I reinstalled the Facebook app
3. I rebooted the device
4. I deleted the application from the list of my Facebook apps (this revokes the access of the app to my data)

None of them seemed to produce results, so I gave up. I didn’t try the process for 4 hours when I got back home. There I reinstalled the Facebook app, after that I managed to successfully login and retrieve the user’s data once again. **I didn't modify any of my code.**

But the problems didn’t stop there. Today after several logins and logouts the issue appeared again and for the past 3 hours I have been able to make it work.

At this point I have really no idea neither why is this happening, nor how to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this kind of behavior?

I am using the Facebook sdk for Android v 3.8.0. I am also testing the app on multiple devices (I am not sure if that’s relevant), the problem so far appears only on Nexus 7 with Jelly Bean, on a Nexus 4 with Kit Kat this has never happened so far.

EDIT:

The code base is quite big, so I will start with some pieces that might be useful, and add more on request:
This handles the session

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "sessionStateChange fired");

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = null;

    switch (session.getState()) {
        case CLOSED:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION CLOSED");
            handleLoginButtonOnClosedSession(fm, currentFragment);

            break;
        case CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION CLOSED LOGIN FAILED");
            handleLoginButtonOnClosedSession(fm, currentFragment);
            break;
        case CREATED:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION CREATED");
            break;
        case CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION CREATED TOKEN LOADED");

            UserWrapper.getCurrentUser(mContext).maintainFacebookToken(mContext);

            break;
        case OPENED:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION OPENED");

            break;
        case OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION OPENED TOKEN UPDATED");

            UserWrapper.getCurrentUser(mContext).maintainFacebookToken(mContext);

            break;
        case OPENING:
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "SESSION OPENING");
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

            if(currentFragment instanceof SplashFragment) {
                SplashFragment splashFragment = (SplashFragment) currentFragment;
                splashFragment.hideLoginButtonForLogin();
            }
            break;
    }

    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (mIsResumed) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // we don't want to clear the back stack if the 
            // home fragment is already showing
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment previousFragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if(previousFragment == null || !(previousFragment instanceof HomeFragment)) {
                clearFramgnets();
            }
            UserWrapper.getCurrentUser(mContext).maintainFacebookToken(mContext);
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(HOME, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "showing splash");
            clearFramgnets();
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(Utils.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Main Activity - onActivityResult called: requestCode="
            + requestCode + " resultCode:" + resultCode);
}
```

Here I try to get the user from Facebook

```
public void logOnApp(final LoginManager loginManager,
        final AppUserLoadedCallback callback) {
    if (mUserId == null || mUserId.getIdFromProvider() == null || getAuthToken() == null) {
        // make request to the /me API
        Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    // callback after Graph API response with sUser object
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            mUserId = new Id(Provider.FACEBOOK, user
                                    .getId());

                            loginManager.increaseSuccesfulRetrievalsCount();

                            fetchUserAuthData(loginManager, callback);
                        } else {
                            // The login has been unsuccessful, if we have reached
                            // the maximum login retries -> logout, else attempt again.
                            if (loginManager.maxRetriesCountReached()) {
                                loginManager.mLogoutRunnable.run();
                            } else {
                                loginManager.increaseRetriesCount();
                                logOnApp(loginManager, callback);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
    } else {
        fetchUserAuthData(loginManager, callback);
    }
}
```

Any new ideas about why is this happening would be really helpful!

Comment: I added some code samples, let me know if you need something more specific!

Comment: you meantion your testing it on 2 devcies what are the facebook version on both devices have your updated them to the latest since with the Facebook App comes the 3.8+ support

Comment: I have the newest Facebook App on both devices. On the one that causes problems I have even reinstalled it couple of times to see if that will make a difference

Comment: I have an update on the topic - I cannot even download Facebook images. It's like the connection to the Facebook servers are blocked by the app or some other program

Comment: maybe somewhere in your code it resends requests a lot of times until Facebook is blocking request cause it thinks your devices is tring DDOS Attack?

Comment: no it shouldn't be that, I'm monitoring the packages that I'm sending from the app, there is no overspam. But I noticed that this might caused by a problem with the https encryption, since trying to load google maps over https also fails.